# How to get selected value from drop down list using knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

So i am using knockout and trying to get the selected item's id in my javascript on the change event. Here is my html

```
 <div id="platforms" data-bind="with: platformsViewModel">
            <p>
                Selected Platform:
                <select data-bind="options: platforms, optionsText: 'displayName', value: 'id', optionsCaption: 'Choose...', event: { change: loadMedias }" ></select>
            </p>
        </div>
```

my view model is as follows

```
my.viewModels.PlatformsViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.platforms = ko.observableArray();
    self.message = ko.observable();

    self.loadMedias = function (data, event) {
        my.loadMedias(data.id);
    }
}
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: thanks for your question, I had a similar problem on a click event in mobile browser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It *looks* like this may be a simple fix, where you're possibly using the `value` binding where you should be using the `optionsValue` binding:

```
<select data-bind="options: platforms, optionsText: 'displayName', optionsValue: 'id', optionsCaption: 'Choose...', event: { change: loadMedias }" ></select>
                                                              <!-- ^ here -->
```

---

However, why not put the logic in the view model, rather than in your view:

```
my.viewModels.PlatformsViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.platforms = ko.observableArray();
    self.message = ko.observable();

    //new observable to hold selected platform
    self.selectedPlatform = ko.observable();
    //subscribe to changes in the observable value to trigger the loading
    self.selectedPlatform.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        my.loadMedias(newValue.id);
    });
}
```

And an updated `<select>` that will bind the actual platform object selected, rather than just its ID:

```
<select data-bind="options: platforms, optionsText: 'displayName', value: selectedPlatform, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'" ></select>
```

Comment: in the view model is a great suggestion, and works like a charm! Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

Html:

```
<select name="ddlUsers" id="ddlUsers" class="form-control"
                            data-bind="options: ViewModel.CashierPage.AvailableCash,  optionsText: 'OptionTextInfo', value: ViewModel.CashierPage.CashSelected, optionsCaption: 'Cassa...'"></select>
```

in js:

```
 public CashSelected: KnockoutObservable();
...
 self.CashSelected = ko.observable(null);
 self.CashSelected.subscribe(function(valueNewValue){/*your code*/});
```